# How to retrieve and send phone contacts data to server using REST API

Tags: java, json, rest, android-asynctask, retrofit2

I would like to know how to retrieve name and phone only information of a phone contacts data and send it to server using async task

MySQL Database columns will look like
name       |  phoneNumber
contactname1        123456